# Proof of Shannon capacity theorem

Tags: communication, wireless, digital-communications

I was looking for a formal proof of the Shannon capacity theorem, which states the condition  which is the maximum data rate possible between two wireless channels. I could not find the proof. Does it appear the proof is done experimentally? Is it correct? Any comment would be appreciated.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with wireless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an application of the [Noisy Channel Coding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem), proof in wikipedia